# Service Bus API Connection for LogicApp doesn't support SAS connection string

Tags: azure-logic-apps, servicebus

I have created a Logic App that utilizes the Service Bus connector. In doing this I created a Service Bus API connection as part of the Logic App, this API connection is used by the Service Bus connector. The Service Bus API connection requires a connection string. The connection string provided from the Azure Portal for the Service Bus topic works fine. However, I want to provide a SAS key (that has an expiration) instead of the Azure Portal provided connection string (which is permanent until manually rotated). When I provide the SAS key to the Service Bus API connection that is used by the Logic App. I get the following error:

```
Unknown Service Bus Token provider found for Service Bus namespace '<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net'
```

I am using the following format in the connection string with the SAS key:

```
SharedAccessSignature={sig};Endpoint={endpoint}
```

The SAS key that I generated for the same Service Bus topic works fine when I create a regular Service Bus consumer in Java and/or .NET. I have created the SAS key for the Service Bus with the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#overview-of-sas

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as you mentioned that Logic App does not support SAS Key as servicebus connection string in the service bus API connector currently.

You could vote the azure feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/31839700-support-service-bus-trigger-with-use-of-sas-token). Now it is under review by Azure App service team.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but instead of using the Connector you can put a Azure Function between the Service Bus and Logic App that handles the receive / send?